# Unable to access variable from base class C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, compiler-errors, clang

I am trying to compile this piece of code on both Linux and Windows for a larger program. The following 3 files are for implementing a simple Linked List.

**linkedList.h:**

```
#ifndef H_LinkedListType
#define H_LinkedListType

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
struct nodeType {
    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};

template<class Type>
class linkedListType {
public:
    const linkedListType<Type>& operator=(const linkedListType<Type>&);    
    void initializeList();
    bool isEmptyList();
    int length();
    void destroyList();
    Type front();
    Type back();
    bool search(const Type& searchItem);
    void insertFirst(const Type& newItem);
    void insertLast(const Type& newItem);
    void deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem);
    linkedListType();
    linkedListType(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList);
    ~linkedListType();

protected:
    int count;
    nodeType<Type> *first;
    nodeType<Type> *last;

private:
    void copyList(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList);
    friend ostream& operator<< <Type> (ostream&, const linkedListType<Type>&);
};

template<class Type>
bool linkedListType<Type>::isEmptyList() {
    return(first == NULL);
}

template<class Type>
linkedListType<Type>::linkedListType() {
    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    count = 0;
}

template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::destroyList() {
    nodeType<Type> *temp;

    while (first != NULL) {
        temp = first;
        first = first->link;
        delete temp;
    }

    last = NULL;
    count = 0;
}


template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::initializeList() {
    destroyList();
}

template<class Type>
int linkedListType<Type>::length() {
    return count;
}

template<class Type>
Type linkedListType<Type>::front() {
    assert(first != NULL);
    return first->info;
}

template<class Type>
Type linkedListType<Type>::back() {
    assert(last != NULL);
    return last->info;
}

template<class Type>
bool linkedListType<Type>::search(const Type& searchItem) {
    nodeType<Type> *current;
    bool found;

    current = first;
    found = false;

    while (current != NULL && !found)
        if (current->info == searchItem)
            found = true;
        else
            current = current->link;

    return found;
}

template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::insertFirst(const Type& newItem) {
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
    assert(newNode != NULL);

    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->link = first;
    first = newNode;

    count++;

    if (last == NULL)
        last = newNode;
}

template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::insertLast(const Type& newItem) {
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;

    newNode = new nodeType<Type>;
    assert(newNode != NULL);
    newNode->info = newItem;
    newNode->link = NULL;

    if (first == NULL) {
        first = newNode;
        last = newNode;
        count++;
    } else {
        last->link = newNode;
        last = newNode;
        count++;
    }
}

template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem) {
    nodeType<Type> *current;
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent;
    bool found;

    if (first == NULL)
        cerr << "Can not delete from an empty list.\n";
    else {
        if (first->info == deleteItem) {
            current = first;
            first = first->link;
            count--;
            if (first == NULL)
                last = NULL;
            delete current;
        } else {
            found = false;
            trailCurrent = first;

            current = first->link;


            while (current != NULL && !found) {
                if (current->info != deleteItem) {
                    trailCurrent = current;
                    current = current->link;
                } else
                    found = true;
            }

            if (found) {
                trailCurrent->link = current->link;
                count--;

                if (last == current)

                    last = trailCurrent;

                delete current;
            } else
                cout << "Item to be deleted is not in the list." << endl;
        }
    }
}

template<class Type>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const linkedListType<Type>& list) {
    nodeType<Type> *current;

    current = list.first;

    while (current != NULL) {
        osObject << current->info << " ";
        current = current->link;
    }

    return osObject;
}

template<class Type>
linkedListType<Type>::~linkedListType() {
    destroyList();
}

template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::copyList
(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList) {
    nodeType<Type> *newNode;
    nodeType<Type> *current;

    if (first != NULL)
        destroyList();

    if (otherList.first == NULL) {
        first = NULL;
        last = NULL;
        count = 0;
    } else {
        current = otherList.first;
        count = otherList.count;
        first = new nodeType<Type>;
        assert(first != NULL);

        first->info = current->info;
        first->link = NULL;

        last = first;
        current = current->link;

        while (current != NULL) {
            newNode = new nodeType<Type>;

            assert(newNode != NULL);

            newNode->info = current->info;
            newNode->link = NULL;

            last->link = newNode;
            last = newNode;

            current = current->link;
        }
    }
}

template<class Type>
linkedListType<Type>::linkedListType
(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList) {
    first = NULL;
    copyList(otherList);
}

template<class Type>
const linkedListType<Type>& linkedListType<Type>::operator=
(const linkedListType<Type>& otherList) {
    if (this != &otherList)
        copyList(otherList);

    return *this;
}

#endif
```

**linkedListForGraph.h:**

```
#ifndef H_LinkedListForGraph
#define H_LinkedListForGraph

#include <iostream>
#include "linkedList.h"

using namespace std;

template<class vType>
class linkedListGraph: public linkedListType<vType> {
public:
    void getAdjacentVertices(vType adjacencyList[], int& length);
};

template<class vType>
void linkedListGraph<vType>::getAdjacentVertices
(vType adjacencyList[], int& length) {
    nodeType<vType> *current;

    length = 0;
    current = first;

    while (current != NULL) {
        adjacencyList[length++] = current->info;
        current = current->link;
    }
}

#endif
```

And a simple **driver.cpp**:

```
#include "linkedListForGraph.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm compiling on windows using the MSVC command line tools using the command:

```
cl driver.cpp /Ehsc /O2
```

It works fine, and as expected I get the driver.exe with zero errors.

Now when I'm compiling on Linux using GCC using the command:

```
g++ driver.cpp -o driver -O3 -Wall -pedantic -Wshadow -Wextra
```

As well as clang:

```
clang++ driver.cpp -o driver -O3 -Wall -pedantic -Wshadow -Wextra
```

I get this weird error from gcc:

```
In file included from driver.cpp:1:0:
linkedListForGraph.h: In member function ‘void linkedListGraph<vType>::getAdjacentVertices(vType*, int&)’:
linkedListForGraph.h:21:15: error: ‘first’ was not declared in this scope
     current = first;
               ^
```

clang outputs:

```
In file included from driver.cpp:1:
./linkedListForGraph.h:21:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'first'
    current = first;
              ^
```

I'm flummoxed with this error as I know that the inheritance is happening clearly and the variable first is accessible from the base class and since the MSVC gave no errors at all, I have no idea what could have I done wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure you don't need all those code for a compilation error. Learn [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you try explicitely: `current = linkedListType<vType>::first;`?

Comment: Also, your title could be more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

```
current = this->first;
```

Comment: Should that be necessary? From the scoping rules, it should check `this` for a member `first` before checking elsewhere.

Comment: @Cyber it is necessary because the base class is a dependant base, and so you have to use `this->` to force two phase lookup.

Comment: @Cyber Yes, it is necessary in standard C++. See the duplicate, where it is well explained.